# Integrate $\int_{|z|=1}z^{3}e^{1/z}dz$ - verification

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I integrate over a circular path centered at 0 with radius 1

$\int_{|z|=1}z^{3}e^{1/z}dz=\int_{|z|=1}z^{3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!z^{n}}dz=\int_{|z|=1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!z^{n-3}}dz$

Then we can switch integration and summation.

$\int_{|z|=1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!z^{n-3}}dz=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^{n-3}}dz=\frac{1}{2!}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}dz=\pi i$

Since for a circular path around $0$ integrals of form

$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^n}dz$

are $0$ for all $n\neq1$ and $2\pi i$ for $n=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost correct.  In your summation the $z^{-1}=1/z$ term comes at $n=3+1=4$, not at $n=3-1=2$.  You should have gotten $i\pi/12$.

Watch your signs!

Answer (score 2):

It is correct. In my opinion, you should add that your series conveges uniformly in $S^1$. Otherwise, you cannot know whether you can exchange the series and the integral.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more explicit then "we can switch integration and summation". However, what exactly is $S^{1}$?

Comment: It is the unit circle.